# How to convert string to workbook name

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub openwb()

Dim x260path As String

x260path = "E:\sarath\PTMetrics\20131002\D8 L538-L550 16MY\D8 L538-L550_16MY_Powertrain Metrics_" & Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD") - 1

Workbooks("x260path").Activate

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ["E:\sarath\PTMetrics\20131002\D8 L538-L550 16MY\D8 L538-L550_16MY_Powertrain Metrics_" & Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD")]

Debug.Print x260path

End Sub
```

Here, when i execute, an error says "subscript out of Range". And it appears on 4th line.when i use 'workbook' to declare 'x260path' instead of string, It shows another error saying "Object variable or with block variable not set" on line 3. Can u help?Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To activate workbook you need to set reference to workbook's name, not workbook's full path & name. Therefore, out of you `x260path` variable you need to get only name. There are few possible ways to do so. This is one I've just have in mind:

```
Dim x260path As String

x260path = "E:\sarath\PTMetrics\20131002\D8 L538-L550 16MY\D8 L538-L550_16MY_Powertrain Metrics_" & Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD") - 1

Dim x260name As String
x260name = Split(x260path, "\")(UBound(Split(x260path, "\")))

Workbooks(x260name).Activate

'the rest of your code here
```